# Docker and DockerHub force to get latest image, but preserve volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have a script to start Docker images pulled from DockerHub

I push the images under respective tags (server and worker)

Here is link to docker compose

https://github.com/marcinguy/scanmycode-ce/blob/master/dockerhub/docker-compose.yml

How do I make update.sh script that will delete current images but preserve volumes and get latest one from DockerHub?

I always push to

```
scanmycode/scanmycode3-ce:server
scanmycode/scanmycode3-ce:worker
```

Is it wrong way to so it? How to achieve it?

Any tips for improving my workflow/setup is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Docker volumes have additional parameters you can use which makes docker-compose ignore the volume creation/deletion. Based on [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#external) - Look under Volumes - Volume configuration reference - external.

So you can then manually create the volumes needed with docker volume [create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) command and then adjust your docker-compose.yml to reference to these volumes. In that case, whenever u call compose up/down it won't create/adjust/remove your volumes.